# Loading metadata with PHP via a JQuery .load call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I  post my code because I am not able to do this step:

-**for each id in ids, creating a new table and loading the metadata into it.**

My problem is to map the correct value of select elements into right table. All values are shown into the first table

```
<?
    $ids = getParam('ids');     
?>![enter image description here][1]

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ids = '<?=$ids?>';  
    var idsArray = ids.split(',');


$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(idsArray , function(index, value){
            loadMetadata(value);
        }); 
}); 
    function loadMetadata(currentId){
        var metadataUrl = url+"?id="+currentId;
        ($("#table"+currentId).find("#data"+currentId)).load(metadataUrl, function() {

            $("ul").each(function(index, value) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("select2-choices")) {                              
                    $(this).removeClass('select2-choices');
                }
        });

        }); 
    }           
</script>
</head>

<body>
<? 
foreach($ids as $id) {
?>
<table  id="table<?=$id?>" class="page-break">
<tr>
<td><div id="data<?=$id?>"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope somebody can help me!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all have you checked your `$ids` ?
What is its value ?

Can you give the resulting HTML (with or without values in the table) ?

The best would be to return with your PHP a string containing a javascript array (`["item1", "item2"]`) so you don't have to split it

Comment: Hi, the $ids is: 2,3,4...the problem is when I modify the component "ul" it seems that it load all data in one table...

Comment: Can I have the HTML code you get in your browser ?
I don't see any ul tag in the code you gave